A way to embed Reports from Power BI Report Server to ASP.NET and Angular project
I want to embed a report hosted on my Power BI Report Server (PBIRS), which is running on a non-closing virtual machine. I've used the rs:embed=true method, and while this does display the report, it prompts for username and password every time the embedded page loads.
Is there a way to bypass this credential prompt so users can view the report without logging in each time? Ideally, I’d like a way to handle the login process behind the scenes while staying within the local report server setup (avoiding the Power BI website).
Anyone know how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!
